# convert from obj-c to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new to iOS and swift.

I am trying to implement SherginScrollableNavigationBar

Here is the code from its demo project:

```
#import "SherginNavigationTableViewController.h"

#import "SherginScrollableNavigationBar.h"

@interface SherginNavigationTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SherginNavigationTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // SherginScrollableNavigationBar
    ((SherginScrollableNavigationBar *)self.navigationController.navigationBar).scrollView = self.tableView;

    self.title = @"ScrollableNavigationBar";
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // SherginScrollableNavigationBar
    ((SherginScrollableNavigationBar *)self.navigationController.navigationBar).scrollView = self.tableView;

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

@end
```

Can someone please help me in converting this code to swift ?

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? It is really very simple. Start with reading a few intro to Swift docs from Apple or any blog. It is the same code written in a different syntax.

Comment: @keithbhunter i have converted it almost. stuck at this part `((SherginScrollableNavigationBar *)self.navigationController.navigationBar).scrollView = self.tableView;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check out [objectivec2swift.net](http://objectivec2swift.net/#/converter)

Converting it makes this:

```
    import "SherginNavigationTableViewController.h"
    import "SherginScrollableNavigationBar.h"

    class SherginNavigationTableViewController {
        func initWithStyle(style: UITableViewStyle) -> AnyObject {
            self = super(style: style)
            if self {
            // Custom initialization
            }
            return self
        }

        func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            // SherginScrollableNavigationBar
           (self.navigationController.navigationBar as 
           SherginScrollableNavigationBar).scrollView = self.tableView


            self.title = "ScrollableNavigationBar"
        }

        func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
                // SherginScrollableNavigationBar
                (self.navigationController.navigationBar as 
           SherginScrollableNavigationBar).scrollView = self.tableView
                super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have tried using it already. i get an error in this line `(self.navigationController.navigationBar).scrollView = self.tableView` saying `UINavigationBar` does not have a member named `scrollView`

Comment: Yeah you have to typecast the SherginScrollableNavigationBar, see my edits

Comment: code compiled without any errors. But after running the application getting this error "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard". i tested my table by running in a simulator before adding this piece of code.

Comment: That's unrelated to this. That has to do with your tableview's code with your custom cell named Cell.

Comment: everything is fine with my tableview's code. I tested it after coding immediately. after SherginScrollableNavigationBar additions it is showing the error

Comment: can u provide me with a demo swift project of [link](https://github.com/shergin/SherginScrollableNavigationBar)

Comment: Well it's saying that you have to reconnect the cell to your storyboard, so I'd assume doing that would fix the problem.

Comment: And no, I'm not translating your project for you. I answered your question so I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer.

Comment: `self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        
        navigationController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: SherginScrollableNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
        
        tableViewController = TableViewController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        
        navigationController!.setViewControllers([self.tableViewController!], animated: false)
        
        self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

Comment: above code is in appdelegate, when i comment out the code table works fine, but sherginFullScrollBar doesnt work. What is the issue ?